# vmware player and hyper-v are not compatible

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, xenserver

I have a xenserver virtualized lab and I'm trying to run some vmware esxi.vmx simulations on windows 7 vm and I am getting the error given below while trying to install vm workstation.

> vmware player and hyper-v are not compatible. remove the hyper-v role from the server before running vmware player.

and

> Error: This product may not be on installed on a computer that has Microsoft installed.

Comment: It's telling you to remove Hyper-V. They can't co-exist.